# How to solve this indefinite integral?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int{(24ab-c-dx)^{3/2}\over a^2-b^2x^2} dx $$  I have tried to solve this integral for a case when $$\ dx=constant$$  inside in a bracket but i am stuck that how to deal this generally.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you mean with $\ dx=constant$ ?

Comment: mean if this whole is constant (24ab−c−constant)3/2 then it will be solve other wise i am stuck please give me hints

Comment: OK, I see now : you mean $d \times x=constant$ not $dx=constant$. These notations are confusing.

Comment: yes sir d is constant mean d.x .simply d multiply with x thanks sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:)**

Let $\dfrac{2ab-c}{d}=A$, $\dfrac{a}{b}=B$ and then substituation $A-x=u^2$
$$
\int{(24ab-c-dx)^{3/2}\over a^2-b^2x^2} dx
=
\dfrac{d^\frac32}{b^2}\int\dfrac{(A-x)^\frac32}{B^2-x^2}dx
=
-2\dfrac{d^\frac32}{b^2}\int\dfrac{u^4}{(B+A-u^2)(B-A+u^2)}du
$$